# Getting the authors to show in the index while using shortauthor and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, indexing

I want to use the abbreviation F/T for a pair of authors but want to see the real names in the index. The package `authorindex` can do this with a special field authauthors, but we are using `biblatex`. Is there a way to reach the same effect with `biblatex`?

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@misc{FreyTappe1991,
        Author = {Frey, Werner and Tappe, Hans Thilo},
        Howpublished = {Manuskript 30. Januar 1991},
        Shortauthor = {F/T},
        authautor = {Frey, Werner and Tappe, Hans Thilo},
        Title = {{Zur Interpretation der X-bar-Theorie und zur Syntax des Mittelfeldes}},
        Year = {1991}}


\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  style=authoryear,
    indexing=true
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}
\clearpage
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}

\clearpage
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}

\clearpage
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}

\clearpage
\printbibliography
%\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can check if `labelname` is one of the `short...` names and index the full version instead. No need for an additional `authautor` field.

```
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shortauthor}
       {\indexnames{author}}
       {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shorteditor}
          {\indexnames{editor}}
          {\indexnames{labelname}}}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}
```

If you have enabled indexing of the bibliography as well (you do in your example), you will need the same for `bibindex`:

```
\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shortauthor}
       {\indexnames{author}}
       {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shorteditor}
          {\indexnames{editor}}
          {\indexnames{labelname}}}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}
```

---

If you insist on a new field, you will need to define a new data model. In the MWE this is created via `filecontents`, but if you intend to use it productively, simply save the file `indexname.dbx` to a location TeX can find it. You can then explicitly give the indexed names in `indexname`.

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{FreyTappe1991,
        Author = {Frey, Werner and Tappe, Hans Thilo},
        Howpublished = {Manuskript 30. Januar 1991},
        Shortauthor = {F/T},
        indexname = {Frey, Werner and Tappe, Hans Thilo},
        Title = {{Zur Interpretation der X-bar-Theorie und zur Syntax des Mittelfeldes}},
        Year = {1991}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{indexname.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=name]{
  indexname}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{indexname}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[
  style=authoryear,
  indexing=true,
  datamodel=indexname,
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\ifnameundef{indexname}
       {\indexnames{labelname}}
       {\indexnames{indexname}}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\ifnameundef{indexname}
       {\indexnames{labelname}}
       {\indexnames{indexname}}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}
\clearpage
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}

\clearpage
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}

\clearpage
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is a further twist. There are people like "Carl J. Pollard", who should be indexed as "Carl Pollard". For this the `authauthor` field would be cool. Is there a way to test for its presence and use it if present?

Comment: Or is this a new question?

Comment: If another entry has a proper corporate author or editor, that would change their indexing too, wouldn't it?

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, but you could argue that that would be a good thing. (I.e. index 'National Aeronautics and Space Administration' instead of 'NASA'.)

Comment: @gusbrs Of course my comment is only valid if the corporate author uses `author` for the long form and `shortauthor` for the short form.

Comment: @StefanMüller If you want a separate field, you will need to order one, see the second part of my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the `shorthand` field instead of `shortauthor`. That means the cite commands will use only the shorthand (and not the year), but it seems to be more inline with what you are intending in the case, actually. Anyway, the year can also be obtained by `\citeyear` (or by adding it manually to the shorthand, as suggested by moewe in the comments).

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@misc{FreyTappe1991,
        Author = {Frey, Werner and Tappe, Hans Thilo},
        Howpublished = {Manuskript 30. Januar 1991},
        shorthand = {F/T},
        authautor = {Frey, Werner and Tappe, Hans Thilo},
        Title = {{Zur Interpretation der X-bar-Theorie und zur Syntax des Mittelfeldes}},
        Year = {1991}}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage[
  style=authoryear,
    indexing=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}

Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}

Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}

Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991} \citeyear{FreyTappe1991}

\printbibliography
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]
[image]

Comment: If there are several works by "F/T" of course one needs to add the year to the shorthand manually.

Comment: @moewe, true, of course. And your comment adds to the suggestion of using `citeyear`. But you got me thinking, would there be a way do add `labelyear` + `extradate` to the shorthand field directly? If so, would it be a good idea?

Comment: Well, you could use a sourcemap to add the `labelyear` to the `shorthand` automatically. You could also change the macros to still print the labeldate even if a `shorthand` is used, but then the `extradate`/`shorthand` extra info are both not the correct fields to disambiguate.