# Getting the name from another field indexed in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, indexing

This is the solution to getting the `author` into the index rather than the `shortauthor`: [Getting the authors to show in the index while using shortauthor and biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402044/getting-the-authors-to-show-in-the-index-while-using-shortauthor-and-biblatex/402067)

But I want to extend on this and have a special field for the value that should appear in the index. The package `authorindex` suggests the field `authauthor` for this (authentical author). The aim is to have one index entry for "Elisabet Engdahl" rather than two:

[image]

So the second entry should not be there.

This is what I cam up with, but it seems to ignore my `authauthor` field:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@misc{FreyTappe1991,
        Author = {Frey, Werner and Tappe, Hans Thilo},
        Howpublished = {Manuskript 30. Januar 1991},
        Shortauthor = {F/T},
        authautor = {Frey, Werner and Tappe, Hans Thilo},
        Title = {{Zur Interpretation der X-bar-Theorie und zur Syntax des Mittelfeldes}},
        Year = {1991}}

@phdthesis{Engdahl1980,
Author = {Engdahl, Elisabet Britt},
authauthor = {Engdahl, Elisabet},
Title = {The Syntax and Semantics of Questions in {Swedish}},
Type = {{PhD} dissertation},
School = {University of Massachusetts},
Note = {[Reproduced by GLSA, University of Massachusetts. Amherst, Ma. 1980]},
Year = {1980}}

@book{Engdahl1986,
Address = {Dordrecht},
Author = {Engdahl, Elisabet},
Publisher = {Reidel},
Title = {Constituent questions. {The} syntax and semantics of questions with special reference to {Swedish}},
Year = {1986}}

\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{authauthor.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=name]{
 authauthor}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{authauthor}
\end{filecontents}



\usepackage[
  style=authoryear,
  indexing=cite,
  datamodel=authauthor
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

%% \renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
%%   \ifciteindex
%%     {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shortauthor}
%%        {\indexnames{author}}
%%        {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shorteditor}
%%           {\indexnames{editor}}
%%           {\indexnames{labelname}}}}
%%     {}}


\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shortauthor}
      {\iffieldundef{authauthor}
        {\indexnames{author}}
        {\indexnames{authauthor}}}
      {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{author}
        {\iffieldundef{authauthor}% if defined use authauthor
          {\indexnames{author}}
          {\indexnames{authauthor}}} % if defined use this field 
        {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shorteditor}
          {\iffieldundef{autheditor}
            {\indexnames{editor}}
            {\indexnames{autheditor}}}
          {\indexnames{labelname}}}}}
    {}}



\begin{document}
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}
\clearpage
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}

\clearpage
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991}

\clearpage
Some text \cite{FreyTappe1991} and \cite{Engdahl1980,Engdahl1986}

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`authauthor` is a name list, so you cannot use `\iffieldundef` you need to use `\ifnameundef`

```
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shortauthor}
      {\ifnameundef{authauthor}
        {\indexnames{author}}
        {\indexnames{authauthor}}}
      {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{author}
        {\ifnameundef{authauthor}% if defined use authauthor
          {\indexnames{author}}
          {\indexnames{authauthor}}} % if defined use this field 
        {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shorteditor}
          {\ifnameundef{autheditor}
            {\indexnames{editor}}
            {\indexnames{autheditor}}}
          {\indexnames{labelname}}}}}
    {}}
```

You also need to declare `autheditor` if you want to use it

```
\begin{filecontents}{authauthor.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=name]{
 authauthor,
 autheditor}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{authauthor,autheditor}
\end{filecontents}
```