# Getting author index to work with \citeauthor

Tags: biblatex

I have a setup in which I use additional BibTeX fields for author/editor names to be used in the index (authauthor, autheditor). See [Getting the name from another field indexed in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402701/18561). For reasons I do not understand this works with normal \cite commands but fails when I use \citeauthor. I redefined `citeindex` maybe this is not called for `\citeauthor`.

```
% call with
% xelatex debug-biber-authorindex.tex
% biber debug-biber-authorindex
% xelatex debug-biber-authorindex.tex
% makeindex -o debug-biber-authorindex.ind debug-biber-authorindex.idx
% xelatex debug-biber-authorindex.tex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@phdthesis{Fokkens2014a,
authauthor = {Fokkens, Antske},
author = {Fokkens, Antske Sibelle},
school = {Department of Computational Linguistics, Universität des Saarlandes},
sortname = {Fokkens, Antske},
title = {Enhancing Empirical Research for Linguistically Motivated Precision Grammars},
year = {2014}}


\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{langsci.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=name]{
  authauthor,autheditor,sortname}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{authauthor,autheditor,sortname}

% for URLs like jstor URLs and MIT handle URLs, ACL antology

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
   stableurl}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{stableurl}


% We also want to have this for books. Otherwise
%
% biber --validate-datamodel main
%
% complains.

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[book,proceedings]{
  booktitle}

% just to get rid of warnings, authors keep supplying publishers with article entries
% St. Mü, 2021-02-11
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[article]{
  publisher}

% St. Mü. 2021-02-11
% our maintainance field. It records whether an item was reviewed or not.
%
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{checked}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{checked}

% \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{checkedseries}
% \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{checkedseries}

% \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{checkednumber}
% \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{checkednumber}


% bibdesk stuff

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
   bdsk-url-1,
   bdsk-url-2,
   bdsk-file-3,
   date-added,
   date-modified,
   read}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{
   bdsk-url-1,
   bdsk-url-2,
   bdsk-file-3,
   date-added,
   date-modified,
   read}

% opt fields

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
%optdate,
opteditor,
optchapter,
optisbn,
optissn,
optmonth,
optpublisher,
optschool,
opturl,
optyear}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{
%optdate,
opteditor,
optchapter,
optisbn,
optissn,
optmonth,
optpublisher,
optschool,
opturl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ResetDatamodelConstraints

% St. Mü. 2021-02-10
\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[
  article,
  book,
  inbook,
  bookinbook,
  suppbook,
  booklet,
  collection,
  incollection,
  suppcollection,
  manual,
  misc,
  mvbook,
  mvcollection,
  online,
  patent,
  periodical,
  suppperiodical,
  proceedings,
  inproceedings,
  reference,
  inreference,
  report,
  set,
  thesis,
  unpublished]{
    \constraint[type=mandatory]{
      \constraintfieldsxor{
        \constraintfield{date}
        \constraintfield{year}
      }
      \constraintfield{checked}  % uncomment for checking
    }
    % if there is an URL then there should be a urldate field.
    \constraint[type=conditional]{
      \antecedent[quantifier=one]{
        \constraintfield{url}
      }
      % biber/biblatex splits urldate into urlyear,urlmoth,ulrday
      \consequent[quantifier=all]{
          \constraintfield{urlyear}
          \constraintfield{urlmonth}
          \constraintfield{urlday}
      }
    }
  }


\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[
  article,
%  book,
  inbook,
%  bookinbook,
%  suppbook,
%  booklet,
%  collection,
  incollection,
  suppcollection,
%  manual,
%  misc,
%  mvbook,
%  mvcollection,
%  online,
%  patent,
%  periodical,
%  suppperiodical,
%  proceedings,
  inproceedings%,
%  reference,
%  inreference,
%  report,
%  set,
%  thesis,
%  unpublished
]{
    \constraint[type=mandatory]{
      \constraintfield{pages}  % uncomment for checking
    }
  }


\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[set]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{entryset}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[article]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{author}
    \constraintfield{journaltitle}
    \constraintfield{title}
% st. mü. 2021-02-13 yes, we want volume and number
% if there is no number, the number field should be filled with "none". This will be surpressed by
% an output filter.
    \constraintfield{volume}
    \constraintfield{number}
    \constraintfield{pages}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[book,mvbook,mvcollection,mvreference,incollection]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{title}
    % Those books that are not in a series have the value none. St. Mü. 2021.02.11
    % The value is suppressed by an outputfilter declaration for biblatex
    \constraintfield{series}
   }
   % if there is a series, there has to be a number. books without a number get the value none.
   % The value none is suppressed by an output filter declaration for biblatex
   \constraint[type=conditional]{
      \antecedent[quantifier=one]{
        \constraintfield{series}
      }
      \consequent[quantifier=all]{
          \constraintfield{number}
      }
    }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[inbook,bookinbook,suppbook]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{author}
    \constraintfield{title}
    \constraintfield{booktitle}
    \constraintfield{publisher}
    \constraintfieldsxor{
       \constraintfield{address}
       \constraintfield{location}
    }
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[booklet]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfieldsor{
      \constraintfield{author}
      \constraintfield{editor}
    }
    \constraintfield{title}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[collection,reference]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{editor}
    \constraintfield{title}
    \constraintfield{publisher}
    \constraintfieldsxor{
       \constraintfield{address}
       \constraintfield{location}
    }
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[incollection,suppcollection,inreference]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{author}
    \constraintfield{editor}
    \constraintfield{title}
    \constraintfield{booktitle}
%\constraintfield{series}
%\constraintfield{number}
    \constraintfield{publisher}
    \constraintfieldsxor{
       \constraintfield{address}
       \constraintfield{location}
    }
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[dataset]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{title}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[manual]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{title}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[misc,software]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{title}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[online]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{title}
    \constraintfieldsor{
      \constraintfield{url}
      \constraintfield{doi}
      \constraintfield{eprint}
    }
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[patent]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{author}
    \constraintfield{title}
    \constraintfield{number}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[periodical]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{editor}
    \constraintfield{title}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[proceedings,mvproceedings]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{title}
    \constraintfield{editor}
    \constraintfield{publisher}
    \constraintfieldsxor{
       \constraintfield{address}
       \constraintfield{location}
    }
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[inproceedings]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{author}
    \constraintfield{editor}
    \constraintfield{title}
    \constraintfield{booktitle}
    \constraintfield{publisher}
    \constraintfieldsxor{
       \constraintfield{address}
       \constraintfield{location}
    }
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[report]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{author}
    \constraintfield{title}
    \constraintfield{type}
    \constraintfield{institution}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[thesis]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{author}
    \constraintfield{title}
    \constraintfield{type}
    \constraintfield{institution}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[unpublished]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{author}
    \constraintfield{title}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints{
  \constraint[type=data, datatype=isbn]{
    \constraintfield{isbn}
  }
  \constraint[type=data, datatype=issn]{
    \constraintfield{issn}
  }
  \constraint[type=data, datatype=ismn]{
    \constraintfield{ismn}
  }
  \constraint[type=data, datatype=pattern, pattern=\regexp{(?:sf|sm|sn|pf|pm|pn|pp)}]{
    \constraintfield{gender}
  }
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[
        natbib=true,
        style=langsci-unified,
        citestyle=langsci-unified,
        datamodel=langsci,   % add authauthor and autheditor as possible fields to bibtex entries
        backend=biber,
        indexing=cite,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{index}
\makeindex

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shortauthor} % If biblatex uses shortauthor as the label of a bibitem
      {\ifnameundef{authauthor}                     % we check whether there is something in authauthor
        {\indexnames{author}}                       % if not, we use author
        {\indexnames{authauthor}}}                  % if yes, we use authauthor
      {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{author}    % if biblatex uses author we similarly test for
                                                    % authauthor and use this field
        {\ifnameundef{authauthor}% if defined use authauthor
          {\indexnames{author}}
          {\indexnames{authauthor}}} % if defined use this field
        {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{shorteditor} % same for editor
          {\ifnameundef{autheditor}
            {\indexnames{editor}}
            {\indexnames{autheditor}}}
          {\indexnames{labelname}}}}}               % as a fallback we index on whatever biblatex used.
    {}}

\begin{document}

Page 1.

\cite{Fokkens2014a}

\newpage

Page 2.

\cite{Fokkens2014a}

\newpage

Page 3.

\citeauthor{Fokkens2014a}

\newpage

Page 4.

\cite{Fokkens2014a}


\printbibliography

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`langsci-unified.cbx`](https://github.com/langsci/langscibook/blob/601a9aa967d24409d09d4bb99986418875266d77/langsci-unified.cbx#L365-L374) defines `\citeauthor` as follows

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

this definition is based on the standard definition from [`biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2163-L2172)

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Hence, those `\citeauthor`s have an explicit

```
\ifciteindex
  {\indexnames{labelname}}
  {}%
```

and don't use `\usebibmacro{citeindex}`. (I guess the idea is that `citeindex` would usually send both the name and the title off to the index, but for `\citeauthor` it is only appropriate to index the name.)

You can change that definition to use `citeindex` instead.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```