# Copy a field value from one field to another if the other field is empty with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I use a setup in which I have a field authauthor which contains a nomralized name of an author that is supposed to show up in the author index. [Getting the name from another field indexed in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402701/18561) I want to use the value of authauthor for sorting as well. So I am looking for something that checks whether the filed sortname has a value and if it does not but authauthor has one, the value of authauthor is copied over to sortname. Can this be doen with biblatex somehow?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}            

\usepackage[
natbib=true,
style=langsci-unified,
citestyle=langsci-unified,
datamodel=langsci,   % add authauthor and autheditor as possible fields to bibtex entries
backend=biber,
indexing=cite
]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@incollection{Steedman89,
        authauthor = {Mark Steedman},
        author = {Steedman, Mark J.},
        pages = {463--504},
        sortname = {Mark Steedman},
        address = {Cambridge},
        booktitle = {Lexical Representation and Process},
        editor = {Marslen-Wilson, William},
        publisher = {The MIT Press},
        title = {Lexical Representation and Process},
        year = {1989},
        title = {Grammar, Interpretation, and Processing from the Lexicon}}

@incollection{Steedman90,
        authauthor = {Mark Steedman},
        author = {Steedman, Mark J.},
        pages = {463--504},
        %sortname = {Mark Steedman},
        address = {Cambridge},
        booktitle = {Lexical Representation and Process},
        editor = {Marslen-Wilson, William},
        publisher = {The MIT Press},
        title = {Lexical Representation and Process},
        year = {1990},
        title = {Grammar, Interpretation, and Processing from the Lexicon}}


@incollection{Steedman91,
        authauthor = {Mark Steedman},
        author = {Steedman, Mark J.},
        pages = {463--504},
        sortname = {Mark Steedman},
        address = {Cambridge},
        booktitle = {Lexical Representation and Process},
        editor = {Marslen-Wilson, William},
        publisher = {The MIT Press},
        title = {Lexical Representation and Process},
        year = {1991},
        title = {Grammar, Interpretation, and Processing from the Lexicon}}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\citep{Steedman89,Steedman90,Steedman91}

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

The example shows that with the field sortname commented out in the second entry, this item gets sorted wrongly. Somehow sortname should be taken over from authauthor.

Comment: Can you tell us where we can get `langsci.dbx`, please? (`langsci-unified` is installed and can be found). On my system I get `file 'langsci.dbx' not found.`, so `authauthor` and friends are not known.

Comment: That said, in absence of a useful MWE I can offer the following unspecific advice: Generally, you can map fields with Biber sourcemaps. There is a function to copy the value of a field X to a field Y only if Y is empty. For this use case that may not be necessary, though, as you could change the sorting template to also take into account the `authauthor` field.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I thought that langsci.dbx would be in the texlive distro. It is here for example: https://github.com/langsci/25/blob/master/langsci.dbx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Biber sourcemap to copy the value of one field into another. One such example (where the first field is also removed) is [How to move the field note at the end of the reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138913/35864).

In your use case that does not appear to be necessary to me, however. It might be easier to just add `authauthor` and `autheditor` to the sorting scheme. Then you no longer need to copy its value to `sortname`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
natbib=true,
style=langsci-unified,
datamodel=langsci, % add authauthor and autheditor as possible fields to bibtex entries
backend=biber,
indexing=cite
]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{nyt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{authauthor}
    \field{author}
    \field{autheditor}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Steedman89,
        authauthor = {Mark Steedman},
        author = {Steedman, Mark J.},
        pages = {463--504},
        sortname = {Mark Steedman},
        address = {Cambridge},
        booktitle = {Lexical Representation and Process},
        editor = {Marslen-Wilson, William},
        publisher = {The MIT Press},
        title = {Lexical Representation and Process},
        year = {1989},
        title = {Grammar, Interpretation, and Processing from the Lexicon}}

@incollection{Steedman90,
        authauthor = {Mark Steedman},
        author = {Steedman, Mark J.},
        pages = {463--504},
        %sortname = {Mark Steedman},
        address = {Cambridge},
        booktitle = {Lexical Representation and Process},
        editor = {Marslen-Wilson, William},
        publisher = {The MIT Press},
        title = {Lexical Representation and Process},
        year = {1990},
        title = {Grammar, Interpretation, and Processing from the Lexicon}}


@incollection{Steedman91,
        authauthor = {Mark Steedman},
        author = {Steedman, Mark J.},
        pages = {463--504},
        sortname = {Mark Steedman},
        address = {Cambridge},
        booktitle = {Lexical Representation and Process},
        editor = {Marslen-Wilson, William},
        publisher = {The MIT Press},
        title = {Lexical Representation and Process},
        year = {1991},
        title = {Grammar, Interpretation, and Processing from the Lexicon}}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\citep{Steedman89,Steedman90,Steedman91}

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

[image: Steedman, Mark J. 1989. Grammar, interpretation, and processing from the lexicon. In William Marslen-Wilson (ed.), Lexical representation and process, 463–504. Cambridge: The MIT Press. Steedman, Mark J. 1990. Grammar, interpretation, and processing from the lexicon. In William Marslen-Wilson (ed.), Lexical representation and process, 463–504. Cambridge: The MIT Press. Steedman, Mark J. 1991. Grammar, interpretation, and processing from the lexicon. In William Marslen-Wilson (ed.), Lexical representation and process, 463–504. Cambridge: The MIT Press.]